# Displaying a field in a column with a fallback option to another field

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I'm creating a view for *Contact* entity and the issue is that some of their sellers have entered information on *Mobile Phone* field, while others used *Business Phone* field.

They'll probably continues to do so. There's no point copying the values as they're entered and both fields are needed.

The simplest solution is to display two columns in the view. However, that occupies the precious width on the form.

I wonder if it's possible to display a column in a view so that it gets its information from field *Ahaa* and if that happens to be empty, it falls back to displaying the field *Buhu*. Is it possible and if so - how?

Answer (score 1):

There's no supported way to add conditional logic to a view definition such that it would show or hide columns. The usual way to do this is to store the value of whichever field is populated in third field.  Populate this in a plugin and show this only in the view.

Comment: Just to clarify - I'm not looking for a way to dynamically display this or that column depending on a condition (which, as you very correctly pointed out, isn't supportedly doable). I'd like a solution, such as the one you describe **but** it needs to be configurable for a junior level customizer (no C# requirement) in case they wish to add more fields to the fallback view. No JS-kungfu for that?